# Correct qualifier (terminology) for this kind of statistics

Tags: terminology

I am doing an analysis of a population of animals that died during the first year of their life. I am comparing them a) to all animals that died, ever, after how-ever long life; and b) animals that did not die and were not born before the earliest birth date in the first-year-death cohort. The data is all categorical and I am trying to tease out differences in the first-year-death cohort as opposed to the two populations (a and b) using things like survival analysis, logistic regression and hypergeometric testing.

**Question**: what kind of statistics is this? I am comparing the "sample" (the first-year-death cohort) to two populations, but I am not looking for information on the population, so it's not inferential. But given that I am using regression, Kaplan-Meier and hypergeometric testing, it is not "Descriptive Statistics", is it? I need to find a qualifier for the analysis before presenting it and I would like to be precise. Statisticians, could someone help me to be accurate, please? Thank you very much.